# Using Phong lighting with directional lighting

Tags: glsl, webgl, phong

I wrote a simple demo-program that applies directional lighting to a scene. Right now I'm getting this image:

[image: Current image I get]

The problem is that I can't figure out how can I set object's material reflection settings (ambient, diffuse, specular, shininess, emission).

Here's my current code:

Vertex shader:

```c
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_normal;

uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 u_worldInverseTransposeMatrix;

varying vec3 v_normal;

void main() {
    // Multiply the position by the matrix.
    gl_Position = u_worldViewProjectionMatrix * a_position;

    // Copy the color from the attribute to the varying.
    v_normal = mat3(u_worldInverseTransposeMatrix) * a_normal;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```c
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 v_normal;

uniform vec3 u_reverseLightDirection;
uniform vec4 u_color;

void main() {
    vec3 normal = normalize(v_normal);

    float light = dot(normal, u_reverseLightDirection);

    gl_FragColor = u_color;

    // Multiplying color portion by the light
    gl_FragColor.rgb *= light;
}
```

Scene-rendering function:

```js
function draw() {
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    // Clear the canvas.
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
    gl.cullFace(gl.BACK);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

    addCubeToScene();
  }

  function addCubeToScene() {
    // Turn on the attribute
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttr.loc);

    // Bind the position buffer.
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, shaderProgram.positionBuffer);

    // Put geometry data into buffer
    setCubeGeometry(gl);

    // Tell the attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
    var type = gl.FLOAT; // the data is 32bit floats
    var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
    var stride = 0; // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
    var offset = 0; // start at the beginning of the buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      positionAttr.loc,
      positionAttr.size - 1,
      type,
      normalize,
      stride,
      offset
    );

    // Turn on the attribute
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(normalAttr.loc);

    // Set normals
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, shaderProgram.normalBuffer);

    // Put normals data into buffer
    setNormals(gl);

    // Tell the attribute how to get data out of normalBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
    var type = gl.FLOAT; // the data is 32bit floating point values
    var normalize = false; // normalize the data (convert from 0-255 to 0-1)
    var stride = 0; // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
    var offset = 0; // start at the beginning of the buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      normalAttr.loc,
      normalAttr.size,
      type,
      normalize,
      stride,
      offset
    );

    // Compute the projection matrix
    var aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
    var zNear = 1;
    var zFar = 2000;
    var projectionMatrix = m4.perspective(
      fieldOfViewRadians,
      aspect,
      zNear,
      zFar
    );

    // Compute the camera's matrix
    var camera = [0, 0, 300];
    var target = [0, 0, 0];
    var up = [0, 1, 0];
    var cameraMatrix = m4.lookAt(camera, target, up);

    // Make a view matrix from the camera matrix.
    var viewMatrix = m4.inverse(cameraMatrix);

    // Compute a view projection matrix
    var viewProjectionMatrix = m4.multiply(projectionMatrix, viewMatrix);

    // Draw a figure at the origin
    var worldMatrix = m4.xRotation(rotation[0]);
    worldMatrix = m4.yRotate(worldMatrix, rotation[1]);
    worldMatrix = m4.zRotate(worldMatrix, rotation[2]);

    worldMatrix = m4.translate(
      worldMatrix,
      translation[0],
      translation[1],
      translation[2]
    );

    worldMatrix = m4.scale(worldMatrix, scale[0], scale[1], scale[2]);

    // Multiply the matrices.
    var worldViewProjectionMatrix = m4.multiply(
      viewProjectionMatrix,
      worldMatrix
    );
    var worldInverseMatrix = m4.inverse(worldMatrix);
    var worldInverseTransposeMatrix = m4.transpose(worldInverseMatrix);

    // Set the matrices
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
      worldViewProjectionMatrixUniform.loc,
      false,
      worldViewProjectionMatrix
    );
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
      worldInverseTransposeMatrixUniform.loc,
      false,
      worldInverseTransposeMatrix
    );

    
    // Set the cube's color
    gl.uniform4fv(colorUniform.loc, [0.3, 0.5, 1, 1]);

    // set the light direction.
    gl.uniform3fv(reverseLightDirectionUniform.loc, m4.normalize([0, 0, 1]));

    // Draw the geometry.
    var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
    var offset = 0;
    var count = 6 * 2 * 3; // 1 face = 2 triangles. 1 triangle = 3 vertices
    gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
  }
```

Comment: *"The problem is that I can't figure out how can I set object's material reflection settings (ambient, diffuse, specular, shininess, emission)."* - Material properties are usually specified in uniform variables as these properties are applied to the entire mesh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Ambient We can take the light's color and  multiply it with a small constant ambient factor, also multiply this with the object's color.

For Reflection we calculate a reflection vector by reflecting the light direction around the normal vector. Then we calculate the angular distance between this reflection vector and the view direction.

```
viewPos is the postion of the camera

In your vertex shader you can calcuate the FragPos like this.
FragPos = vec3(u_worldViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(a_position));

Calculate the viewDir in Fragment shader
vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);


Fragment Shader
vec3 CalcDirLight(Light light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir)
    {
      // vector to point from the light source towards the fragment's position
       vec3 lightDir = normalize(-light.direction);
       
       // diffuse shading
       float _diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
       
       // specular shading
       vec3 halfWay = normalize( lightDir + viewDir);
       
       float spec = pow(max(dot(halfWay, normal), 0.0), material.shininess);
       vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * material.specular;
      
       vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * _diff * material.diffuse ; 
          
       
       vec3 ambient = 0.2 * (light.ambient * material.ambient );
      
        return (ambient + diffuse + specular + material.emission ) ;
      
    }
```